# Can not connect to EC2 instace using gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, gitlab

There are two pipelines in gitlab --> build & deploy

In deploy pipeline I want to copy dist folder into my ec2 directory that's why I want to ssh into my ec2.

command I have put in yml file & settled variables also :

```
$ ssh -tt -i $Server_pem ubuntu@Server_IP
```

but when deploy pipeline it shows error :

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname server_ip: Name or service not known
```

**Ec2 Instance Details :**

Ubuntu AMI
Using Public DNS / IP : ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
Instance can be accessed from outside ( configured security group for this)

**GitLab Details :**

I'm using Gitlab shared runners for this (Personal account) &
Added SHA (RSA) key in Server_pem file in variables for connection EC2

help me to solve this issue and if any other way I can copy my build please let me know.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You have to post more details about AWS setup and Gitlab setup as well.
About AWS/EC2, are you using public IP or private IP for connection? Are they inside private/public subnet and can be accessed from outside? How is Gitlab configured? Managed cloud hosting or self hosted on any server and how it communicates with EC2 network?
Please post such details by editing the question.

Comment: @saurabh14292 Hello , Thank you for reply , edited my question and provided some extra details please check it.